# Transpose and multiplication of arrays

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using the Arduino DUE and I'm trying to find a way to transpose an array.

For example if I have this array:

```
int A[5] ={1, 2, 3,4,5};
```

It's basically an array with 1 row and 5 columns. After transpose it should be 5 rows of 1 column.

Do you know how to do that without using any library?

Comment: why would you want to transpose arrays in arduino? If we are talking about transposing, we are talking about two dimensional arrays, so you can do it easily: `int A[1][5]; int B[5][1]; for (i=0; i<5; i++) A[0][i] = B[i][0]'`

Comment: One dimensional array only? You don't need separate implementation then, just add a boolean flag if the array should be treated as disposed or not...

Comment: Why not use a std::vector? What if the size/row/col is unknown.

Comment: @gchen Arduino doesn't support std vector as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if you have a 2-D array of (m x n) order then create a new array of order (n x m). This can be done by using a nested loop to iterate through the array of order (n x m) and copy the elements of the array of order (m x n) so all you have to do is--->

a[m][n] -----> Initial array(Input)
b[n][m] -----> New required array(output-Transpose)

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        b[i][j]=a[j][i];
    }
}
```

Thus, this gives you the required array b[n][m] which is the transpose of a.

Comment: You cannot have use formatting in code sections... Find some other way to hightlight important passages.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question but I believe you have a misconception of what an array is, an array is not one row with multiple columns or a column with multiple rows, **is just a sequence of stored values in memory**.

That means ar array doesn't have a defined shape, the coder is usually the one who shapes it so you can use it as a 1x5 or 5x1 matrix depending on the way you iterate over it.